Why the nickname Tuppence?
The Secret Adversary by Agatha Christie (freely/legally available to read online) is the first novel featuring the detective duo Tommy and Tuppence. The latter is introduced as follows:

Miss Prudence Cowley, known to her intimate friends for some mysterious reason as “Tuppence.”

Is the reason for this nickname ever explained in the novels? (For non-Brits, "tuppence" means two pennies, a small amount of money.) Why did her friends call her by this particular name, which doesn't bear a strong resemblance (except the ending) to her real name?

In my memory, Tuppence was a nick-name used by older relatives for young children.

Sometimes written twopence but pronounced tuppence.

The actress Tuppence Middleton, in an article linked from the Wikipedia page about her, says "It’s what my grandma called my mother as a little girl and my parents decided to call me that."

A guess: maybe for the similarity of sound (a rhyme, and part Spoonerism) between ‘Prudence’ and ‘two pence’?

@gidds The pronunciation of "tuppence" isn't anything like that though: it's "u" as in "cut", not as in "fruit".

@Randal'Thor Yes, yes.  But (depending on where you're from) there are ways of pronouncing the two words ‘Two’ ‘Pence’ that are vaguely similar to ‘Prudence’.  And then, from there, the jump to ‘Tuppence’ could be by analogy with the usual meaning.

How about a nickname for someone who is good at giving her two cents'/pence worth in comments? It fits in Tuppence Cowley's case, anyway, I believe.
I love her real name and her nickname, and she is my favourite Agatha Christie character. The second syllable rather rhymes to my ear ( "ence").

Hello and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please take our tour! Unlike other discussion sites, we require that answers be supported with evidence. Is this explanation given in any of the works featuring the Beresfords, or it it just a guess on your part? If the former, please edit your answer to quote the relevant portion of the work. If the latter, this answer might be deleted or turned into a comment on the question by the moderators. Thanks!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
